# Mark html table line if the line have zero in specific cell

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table with result from a database table. Here is my code:

```
<?php
 $todayDate = date("Y-m-d");
 $sqlTruck = "SELECT * FROM `truckRecords` WHERE truckWeightDateTimeFull between '$todayDate 00:00:00' and '$todayDate 23:59:59' ORDER BY id DESC";
 $result = $connection->query($sqlTruck);
 // output data of each row
 echo "<table style='width:100%;'  class='tableResults'>
     <tr class='topLine'>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>User ID</th>
         <th>Ημερομηνία - ώρα</th>
         <th>Βάρος</th>
         <th>Υλικό</th>
         <th>Εταιρεία</th>
         <th>Είδος Οδηγού</th>
         <th>Τιμ/γιο</th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
     </tr>";
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr id='".$row["id"]."'>
             <td class='thRecordID'>".$row["id"]."</td>
             <td>".$row["UserId"]."</td>
             <td>".$row["truckWeightDateTimeFull"]."</td>
             <td class='weightProduct'>".$row["weightProduct"]."</td> // <-- If this cell is equal with zero, addClass "zeroweight" in this table line
             <td>".$row["material"]."</td>
             <td>".$row["companyName"]."</td>
             <td>".$row["driverKind"]."</td>
             <td>".$row["invoice"]."</td>
             <td><a href='#' id='".$row['id']."' class='editRecord'><i class='fas fa-eye'></i> / <i class='fas fa-print'></i></td>
             <td><a href='#' id='".$row['id']."' class='deleteRecord'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></a></td>
             <td><a href='#' id='".$row['id']."' class='edit_data'><i class='fas fa-pencil-alt'></i></a></td>
          </tr>";
          }
     echo "</table>";
 ?>
```

As you can see a have cell in table with `className: "weightProduct"`.
I am looking for a solution, when the value in cell with class name "weightProduct" equal with zero, addclass "zeroweight" in the table line which combine them.

After that I will use class name with CSS to modified the this line

I tried this with Javascript code but it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("td.weightProduct").text() == 0){
        $("td.weightProduct").parent().addClass("zeroweight");
    }else{
        $("td.weightProduct").addClass("Nozeroweight");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating the `td` inside a `while` loop, I assume there are multiple.

So when you write `$("td.weightProduct").text()` you will get back the concatenation of the texts of all the `td` with a class of `weightProduct`, that's why `$("td.weightProduct").text()` never equals to `0` because probably you have at least one `td.weightProduct` with a non `0` value.

What you need is, to loop through the elements and change the ones with a `0` value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td.weightProduct").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 0) {
      $(this).parent().addClass("zeroweight")
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("Nozeroweight");
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: tpt re patrioti :D

Comment: ela re rokabili! euxaristw k pali

Answer (score 0):

$("td.weightProduct").text() will return all the values of weightProduct in a single string. You have to separate each td and evaluate if the value is 0

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var arr = $("td.weightProduct")
for( var i=0; i<arr.length; i++ ){
if($(arr[i]).text() == 0){
$(arr[i]).parent().addClass("zeroweight");
}else{
$(arr[i]).addClass("Nozeroweight");
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not handle it server side?

Create a variable to hold the class for your cell. Check the value and change the class accordingly.

```
<?php
 $todayDate = date("Y-m-d");
 $sqlTruck = "SELECT * FROM `truckRecords` WHERE truckWeightDateTimeFull between '$todayDate 00:00:00' and '$todayDate 23:59:59' ORDER BY id DESC";
 $result = $connection->query($sqlTruck);
 // output data of each row
 echo "<table style='width:100%;'  class='tableResults'>
     <tr class='topLine'>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>User ID</th>
         <th>Ημερομηνία - ώρα</th>
         <th>Βάρος</th>
         <th>Υλικό</th>
         <th>Εταιρεία</th>
         <th>Είδος Οδηγού</th>
         <th>Τιμ/γιο</th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
     </tr>";
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     //Changes from here
     $wpClass = "weightProduct";
     if($row["weightProduct"] == 0) {
         $wpClass += " zeroweight"
     }
     echo "<tr id='".$row["id"]."'>
             <td class='thRecordID'>".$row["id"]."</td>
             <td>".$row["UserId"]."</td>
             <td>".$row["truckWeightDateTimeFull"]."</td>
             <td class='" . $wpClass . "'>".$row["weightProduct"]."</td> // <-- If this cell is equal with zero, addClass "zeroweight" in this table line
             <td>".$row["material"]."</td>
             <td>".$row["companyName"]."</td>
             <td>".$row["driverKind"]."</td>
             <td>".$row["invoice"]."</td>
             <td><a href='#' id='".$row['id']."' class='editRecord'><i class='fas fa-eye'></i> / <i class='fas fa-print'></i></td>
             <td><a href='#' id='".$row['id']."' class='deleteRecord'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></a></td>
             <td><a href='#' id='".$row['id']."' class='edit_data'><i class='fas fa-pencil-alt'></i></a></td>
          </tr>";
          }
     echo "</table>";
 ?>
```

**NOTE** my PHP is a little rusty so some debugging will be required.

If you *really* want to do this client side, this should be the simplest way to do it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("td.weightProduct").filter(function(){return $(this).text() === "0";}).addClass("zeroweight");
});
```